# MVC How to pass & read the id values of dynamically generated rows

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a page which displays a table with employee name id, etc. There is edit link with each item. when user click edit link then it opens a new modal box with the employee details. 
The modal widow has same model as parent window. In fact I am passing the same model to modal window.

Please note I do not want to invoke any action method when user click edit link. I simply show the details (in text fields)when edit button is clicked. When user click save button after editing then I invoke action to update the database.

I am using code first approach

Please consider following code

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication1.Models.employee>
```

......

```
         @foreach (var item in Model) {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.name)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.age)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.address)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @* I want to pass the value of employee ID when user click this link *@
                        <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" id="editlink1" >Edit..</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
```

//////

```
             <!-- Modal -->
                <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                               Name of the Employee clicked is <TODO>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                            </div>
                        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
                    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
                </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

**I want to know how can I pass the employee id when edit link is clicked, also how to access the passed values in the Modal window.**

Please note the model for Index & modal window is same, this is because  in modal window I have option to move to next record.

Comment: Where us your `jQuery` code?

Comment: Sorry I am new to both Jquery and MVC. I have not yet written any jQuery code for this, In fact I want to know how to pass ID which can be accessed in Modal window. Can we do this with Jquery?

Answer (score 1):

While generating the links dynamically through foreach loop , give the links a class like linkEmployee and give an id to all of them like lnkEmployee_+EmployeeID
so your links will be like lnkEmployee_2,lnkEmployee_4,lnkEmployee_5 where 2,4 and 5 will be your employee id's.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     var EmployeeID='';

     $('.linkEmployee ').click(function(){
     //Get the ID of currently clicked link like.
     var ID= $(this).attr('id');

     //split the ID by '_' and get the employee ID as below
     EmployeeID=ID.split('_')[1];

     //Employee ID is the desired ID on the Edit click which will be present globally                           everyehere in the javascript. you can use this ID to open your MODAL popup .


     lblHiddenEmployeeID.text(EmployeeID);
     })        
})
```

After getting this global Employee ID you can assign this ID as a text to a label which is present in Your MODAL BOX as a hidden field.

You can use this label text the way you want in your MODAL BOX.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You should do this via Javascript or preferably using jQuery. Everytime when you do not need to make a call to a server it is a prefered solution to use some client-side programming (JS).

To get a quick start on jQuery:

> http://learn.jquery.com/

Comment: This really isn't useful. Maybe an example of how to do something like that would be more useful.. than asking him to learn jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

use your partial or normal view

```
 foreach (var item in Model)
    {
    ...
    ...
    <p class="row-doctor-details-row1"><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#@item.Id"> @item.Name</a></p>
    ....
    ...
    <div class="modal fade" id="@item.Id" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    ...
    your details to show
    ...
    <div>
    }
```